# Torch test.sh, /usr/bin/lua: module 'paths' not found

Tags: linux, machine-learning, lua, torch

I am trying to install `torch` in `linux mint`.

Here is my `/etc/linuxmint/info` output

```
RELEASE=17.2
CODENAME=rafaela
EDITION="Cinnamon 64-bit"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela"
DESKTOP=Gnome
TOOLKIT=GTK
NEW_FEATURES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_rafaela_cinnamon_whatsnew.php
RELEASE_NOTES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_rafaela_cinnamon.php
USER_GUIDE_URL=help:linuxmint
GRUB_TITLE=Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64-bit
```

I have installed `lua`.

```
$ which lua
/usr/bin/lua

$ lua -v 
Lua 5.2.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2013 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

Then, I have installed `torch` using the following commands

```
git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
cd ~/torch; bash install-deps;
./install.sh
```

The installation completes successfully.

However, when I type `th` I get `th: command not found`.

Also, when I run the `test.sh` script I get,

```
/usr/bin/lua
/usr/bin/lua: module 'paths' not found:
    no field package.preload['paths']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/paths.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/paths/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/paths.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/paths/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/paths.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/paths/init.lua'
    no file './paths.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/paths.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/paths.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/paths.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './paths.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function '_G.require'
    [C]: in ?
```

what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `. ~/torch/install/bin/torch-activate` in `~/.bashrc` makes the `test.sh` script run.

Comment: Keep in mind that adding `torch-activate` sets **lua5.1** as your default lua interpreter which *might* break some apps using **lua5.3** ("awesome" window manager). Because of that, I call `torch-activate` separately per terminal session only. Also, be aware of the **luajit** memory limitations which might bite you back when you'll be writing  model boilerplate code.

Comment: i added it to the ./test.sh and it worked like a charm

Comment: I already had this in my .bashrc file, but tesh.sh prints the same error for me as in the question, except it is all lua 5.1 instead of lua 5.2.

Did I do something really stupid, like not even install lua? But `lua -v` says "Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio"

.... and just like everything else, rebooting solved the problem. :|