# module 'paths' not found:

Tags: lua, torch

Problem using torch library on Windows:

SciTE:

```
lua: init.lua:12: module 'paths' not found:
no field package.preload['paths']
no file '.\paths.lua'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\paths.lua'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\paths\init.lua'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\paths.lua'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\paths\init.lua'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\paths.luac'
no file '.\paths.dll'
no file '.\paths51.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\paths.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\paths51.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\paths.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\paths51.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\loadall.dll'
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\loadall.dll'
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'require'
init.lua:12: in main chunk
[C]: ?
Exit code: 1
```

do not write about Linux, I saw: [Torch test.sh, /usr/bin/lua: module 'paths' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348407/torch-test-sh-usr-bin-lua-module-paths-not-found)

Does anyone have file: paths.lua?

Answer (score 0):

I also got this same error I find a solution from stack**overflow**.

By Adding. `/torch/install/bin/torch-activate`

in your `bashrc` file and makes the `test.sh` script run.